# Copy files from list of files and create necessary directory structure

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, copy

I have a file list like below:

```
app/code/community/Company/Module/Block/Adminhtml/BlockAlias.php
app/code/community/Company/Module/Block/Adminhtml/BlockAlias/Edit.php
app/code/community/Company/Module/Block/Adminhtml/BlockAlias/Grid.php
app/code/community/Company/Module/Block/Adminhtml/BlockAlias/Import.php
...
```

Now I want to copy these files to a new folder and automatically create directories and subfolders separated by `/`.

Any suggestions or help ?

Comment: Try `rsync`. It can read from a list of files, and it will re-create the directory structure.

Comment: I'm not sure right now, but does not `cp` an option for recursively copy files?  Maybe `cp -r app/code community/Company/module/Block/Adminhtml/ /desired_directory/` could work (This would copy every file and folder in `.../Adminhtml/` so if there are more files or folders than those you have indicated and you don't want to copy them, then this command won't work for you)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cpio`'s pass-through mode with the `-d` option for that job:

```
cpio -p -d DESTINATION < FILELIST
```

This will create a copy of the whole directory structure specified in `FILELIST` (relative to the current working directory) underneath `DESTINATION`. With your example you will then have `DESTINATION/app/code/community/Company/Module/Block/Adminhtml/BlockAlias.php` etc.

Comment: Thanks @David Foerster, I will try that in Office where I have Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr version.

Comment: how to change current directory by using dots and slashes in the text file where paths are stored ?

Comment: My script should change directory(go to the immediate parent folder) before reading every line and then copy according to the path in the line.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Please edit your question if you want to alter its scope and clarify what you want as best as you can e. g. by including an example. Ping me when you're done so I can respond to the changes.